# How to show file content into a HTML to make it as complete HTML

Tags: html

I was planning to construct an HTML file which takes the input from another file.

#### Example

I want write an HTML file as follows:

```
<html>
.
.
//file content
.
</html>
```

File as follows:

```
<td> </td>
.
.
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using the jQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function, but it is better to use another container rather than the **HTML** element tag. A div for example:

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

And your JavaScript code using jQuery:

```
$('#container').load('path/to/your/file.html');
```